# C# - Create a derived class instance from string then add to base class list

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, activator

I'll be reading a string input that will determine what type of derived class to create. The object created then gets added to a list of baseclass objects.

When trying to add the the result of `Activator.CreateInstance();` to the list I get:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Namespace.Animal'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

I've gotten the below:

```
List<Animal> animals;

Type animal_type = Type.GetType(class_name); // eg lion, tiger
object new_animal = Activator.CreateInstance(animal_type);

animals.Add(new_animal);
```

How can I add the newly created object to the list?

Comment: Can't you directly get the type you want to create? (I mean pass the Type instead of a string)

Comment: You should cast your created object to Animal before adding it to the animals list.

Comment: Read the error message again.

Comment: well, its basicly right. Activator gives you a `object` object and you require animal. you can cast that to animal of course

Comment: I didn't cast to base class because I wasn't sure if I would lose the derived class functionality. Thanks for the downvotes despite the title specifically mentioning this fact.

Comment: If you mouse over a downvote it says "This question does not show any research effort..." The error message is fairly obvious about what is wrong, your question does not show any research effort on your part. If you real concern is if a derived class is stored as its base class you loose some features you should have asked that instead and left out the part about `Activator`.

Comment: Didn't know you could see those comments. I included the part about `Activator` because I thought it would be relevant. I included the code I had so far. Thought that's enough to solve the issue and it was.

Comment: @MrWednesday hmm so the idea is that you were okay with it being stored as an `object` but not an `Animal`

Comment: No, thus the need to ask how to create it as the derived class. I didn't want it as an `Animal` or an `object`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says, you need an [explicit cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s682k58%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
animals.Add( (Animal) new_animal);
```

`new_animal` is of type `object`. So, `new_animal` could be just about anything. The compiler needs you to explicitly tell it to take the dangerous step of assuming it's of type `Animal`. It will not make that assumption on its own because it cannot guarantee the conversion will work.

Comment: @MrWednesday No, you just need to detect which derived class it is when you pull it out of the list and do a further cast on it.

Answer (score 3):

Cast the result from Activator.CreateInstance to Animal:

```
List<Animal> animals;

Type animal_type = Type.GetType(class_name); // eg lion, tiger
Animal new_animal = (Animal)Activator.CreateInstance(animal_type);

animals.Add(new_animal);
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend on the other answers you need to cast to `Animal` first. However if you are not 100% sure that you will be getting a class derived from `Animal` every time here is a better way to check.

```
Type animal_type = Type.GetType(class_name); // eg lion, tiger
object new_object = Activator.CreateInstance(animal_type);

Animal new_animal = new_object as Animal; //Returns null if the object is not a type of Animal

if(new_animal != null)
    animals.Add(new_animal);
```

The other answers will throw an exception if the type you passed in to `class_name` was not a type of `Animal`, this method will just not add it to the list and continue on.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is **Implicit** casting. you should cast **Explicitly** instead. Try:

```
object new_animal = (Animal) Activator.CreateInstance(animal_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, you need to cast your Object to Animal.  But you probably should check to be sure the type you are creating is assignable to Animal before instantiating your object.

```
  public bool AddNewAnimal(List<Animal> animals, string className)
  {
     bool success = false;

     Type animalType = Type.GetType(className);
     if (typeof(Animal).IsAssignableFrom(animalType))
     {
        object newAnimal = Activator.CreateInstance(animalType);
        animals.Add((Animal)newAnimal);
        success = true;
     }

     return success;
  }
```